# Как добавить drag'n'drop компонент в iblock.element.add.form. Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Добрый день. Может кто нибудь из гуру битрикса знает, как добавить drag'n'drop в редактирование формы iblock.element.add.form.
Есть форма редактирования своих заявок у каждого пользователя.

[image: Как выглядит это в админке битрикса]

Этот drag'n'drop хотелось бы использовать в своей форме редактирования заявок у пользователей:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне это осуществить??

Comment: В штатном режиме насколько я знаю функционал drag'n'drop поддерживается. Пробовали перетащить файл на кнопку? Если не подходит внешний вид или не работает, то модифицируйте с помощью jquery.

Comment: @NikolajSarry первым делом пробывал, безрезультатно.  Ну придется с jquery, думал в битриксе это просто делается

Comment: Странно. Просто проверял на своих сайтах у меня отрабатывает перетаскивание.